# Make PHP generated URL trigerable in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php script that I'm trying to trigger with Javascript. I'm trying to set the URL dynamically with php using a variable but am not having any luck, does anyone know how I should approach this?

```
<a href="#" onclick="return getOutput();">Click here</a>

<?php $update_url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/xyz.php'; ?>

function getOutput() {
  getRequest(
    var str = "<?php echo $update_url ?>", // URL for the PHP file
       drawOutput,  // handle successful request
       drawError    // handle error
  );
  return false;
}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error. `var str = `

Comment: would the url not be a sting?

Comment: It should be an string, but it looks to me that you're passing 3 arguments to `getRequest()` function, so you cannot have `var str = ` there. You could define it some where else or directly pass it

Comment: `var` is a statement, not an expression. You can't use statements as arguments.

Comment: just remove 'var str = '. as Adam Azed told.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have `var str =` as a parameter to a `function()`. You can't write

```
functionName(var a='a', b); // this will not work
```

This is a way to solve that:

```
function getOutput() {
  var str = "<?php echo $update_url ?>"; // URL for the PHP file
  getRequest(
       str,
       drawOutput,  // handle successful request
       drawError    // handle error
  );
  return false;
}
```

and this way is shorter:

```
function getOutput() {
  getRequest(
       <?php echo $update_url ?>, // URL for the PHP file
       drawOutput,  // handle successful request
       drawError    // handle error
  );
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do; pass the PHP value as an string.

```
<?php $update_url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/xyz.php'; ?>

function getOutput() {
  getRequest(
       "<?php echo $update_url ?>", // URL for the PHP file
       drawOutput,  // handle successful request
       drawError    // handle error
  );
  return false;
}
```

#### OR

Define as JavaScript value in the global scope (this may not work)

```
var updateURL = "<?php $update_url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/xyz.php'; ?>";

function getOutput() {
  getRequest(
       updateURL, // URL for the PHP file
       drawOutput,  // handle successful request
       drawError    // handle error
  );
  return false;
}
```